# R reshape2 - transform 6 cols into 2 columns

Tags: r, reshape2

I am given a data set with these columns:

```
ID  |  X_B_Rate  |  X_D_Rate  |  Y_B_Rate  |  Y_D_Rate  | Z_B_Rate  | Z_D_Rate
```

As you can see, the columns kind of repeat itself, the challenge is to write R code and transform the columns into:

```
ID  | x_or_y  |  B_or_D  |  Rate
```

I have tried reshape2's `melt()` function, but I can't wrap my head around how RegExp works with it

```
test <- melt(df, id.vars=c('ID'), measure.vars=grep('X$',colnames(df)), 
variable.name='x_or_y', value.name='Rate')
```

I know the code is definitely wrong. I'm only getting a list of IDs, I can't seem to understand how the RegExp works with the `melt()` function and I have tried googling "Reshape2 melt()" but everywhere there's only a very short doc on it.

I would totally appreciate if someone could tell me what am I doing wrong or at least point me in a the correct direction to the proper doc.

Comment: Could you provide sample data using `dput(yourdf)` for better results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
yourdf %>% 
  gather("id","value",1:ncol(.))
```

You can then rename your columns in whichever way you wish.
EDIT: Using `reshape2` you could do something like this:

```
yourdf%>% 
  mutate(ID=row_number()) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars=c("ID"))
```

I've used my own data to exemplify as your question provides no sample data.